# Windows Phone 8: Convert c# filename to c ASCII

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8, ascii

I want to open a file with a filename which contains special characters such as äöüó, etc. The filename is passed from C# to a C++ Windows Runtime component:

C#:

```
String filename= "testöäüßó.xyz";
RuntimeComponent rt = new RuntimeComponent();
rt.processFile(filename;
```

C++:

```
RuntimeComponent::processFile(String^ fn)
{
    // Convert from wstring to string (UTF8)
    typedef std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> convert_type;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_type, wchar_t> converter;
    std::string str = converter.to_bytes(fn->Data());

    // Open
    fopen(str.c_str(), "r");
}
```

Obviously the string conversion will not work as it returns UTF8 encoded strings. What is the right way to get correct characters of the passed filename?

Regards,

Comment: why you need convert? As C# String is UTF-16, if you use std::wstring, then it should be just fine.

Comment: The problem is that I need to pass the filename to C functions (e.g. fopen) which require an ASCII (const char*) string as parameter. And this will not work with the conversion I have posted.

In iOS there is a useful method `NSString fileSystemRepresentation]` which converts NSString to ASCII in a way that the file can be opened.

Comment: You can also use unicode API: _wfopen

Comment: This is a great idea for functions where I have access to the source code. Unfortunately I am also using 3rd party libraries which only take const char* as input arguement.